# Converting from Nginx to apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I am trying to set up a site which uses code cloned from http://usesthis.com/

My site is at http://hackingtheuniversity.net/

You'll see that each interview post on the site, uses the following URL syntax

http://firstname.lastname.hackingtheuniversity.net

The creator of the original site uses Nginx and has offered the following for how he achieves this syntax

https://gist.github.com/1840543

I've set up wildcard DNS and a ServerAlias of *.hackingtheuniversity.net, but I'm struggling to understand (and find examples) how to port the Nginx rules to modrewrite rules and would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z+.-]+).hackingtheuniversity.net/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /interviews/%1.html [L]

should do the trick.